# Is it ok to forward a JWT between two custom services?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

I'm using Azure AD Implicit Flow for authentication between a SPA and a WebApi.

I want to know if it would be ok/save to redirect from the SPA to a intermediary service of my own as well with the BearerToken, and forward once more, from there, the Bearer token to the WebApi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they belong to the same security domain (i.e. under control by the same entity) in principle that is not a problem. You should take precautions against token leakage/exposure, as always.